# Event handler / trigger for when web browser's autofill is used

Tags: javascript, html, browser, autocomplete, autofill

I have a form with inputs with labels hovering above them as placeholders. As the user types text, these labels are hidden. My problem is however when browser [autofill](http://support.google.com/chrome/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=142893) is fired, and chrome for example populates all the inputs with values, my labels are left visible, creating overlapping of label text, and input text. I need a trigger that is fired when autofill is used so I can hide these labels.

[I have found *a* hack solution](http://furrybrains.com/2009/01/02/capturing-autofill-as-a-change-event/), but it requires a timer that constantly checks each input value and listens for changes. This isn't ideal to me because of resource consumption, and its a lot of code for a simple function.

Is there a event listener or something to this effect, so that if an input is autocompleted, it would trigger a function of my own?